# Refreshing view panel from dojo widget

Tags: dojo, calendar, xpages

Got this code from @MichaelSaiz and altered it slightly, and the calendar widget looks/works great with the Calendar.css  that comes with dojo 1.5.x on the Domino server.

However, I need to refresh a Calendar view when the user clicks on a date, and although fields are being refreshed OK, the view is behaving strangely, and I can't see why?

XSP.addOnLoad(function(){

```
    dojo.require("dojox.widget.Calendar");
    dojo.require("dojo.date","dijit.registry"); 
    dojo.require("dojo.date.locale");
    dojo.require("dijit.Calendar");
    dojo.ready(function(){      
        // create the Calendar:
        var selectedDate = null;

        var calendar_body = new dojox.widget.Calendar({
                value: new Date(),

                onValueSelected: function(date){calendarDateClicked(date);
                }
            }, "calendar_body");


        //create Click action
        function calendarDateClicked(date){
            var d = new Date(date);

            var month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
            var day = '' + d.getDate();
            var year = d.getFullYear();
            if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
            if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;


            var dateString = [day,month,year].join("/");

            var y = dojo.date.locale.format(d, {datePattern:"dd/MM/yyyy", selector: 'date'});


            //dojo.byId('#{id:hiddenCalWidgetSelectedDate}').value = dateString
            dojo.byId('#{id:hiddenCalWidgetSelectedDate}').value = y;

            dojo.byId('#{id:calDate}').value = y;
            //dojo.byId('#{id:calDate}').value = dateString;
            XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:dayPanel1}",{});//Post Value to server
        }
    });
});
```

This fires when the user clicks the calendar and it updates a field (calDate) and then updates the viewPanel (dayPanel1).

The view is filtered based on a calDate field which clicking on the calendar sets.

Any ideas how I can get the view refreshed when the user clicks on the calendar? Seems basic but it's driving me nuts!!

Graeme

Comment: It seems that the view does not find entrys for your filter.  Maby doublecheck the Filter value.

Comment: Hi @MichaelSaiz, I should have said that one of my tests was to add the date/time field just above the view and then change the date using that instead of the calendar. It worked OK using that method - which still set the sessionScope variable and then did a partial refresh on the viewPanel. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

The date format was incorrect (as @MichaelSaiz surmised). Got it sorted now.

XSP.addOnLoad(function(){

```
    dojo.require("dojox.widget.Calendar");
    dojo.require("dojo.date","dijit.registry"); 
    dojo.require("dojo.date.locale");
    dojo.require("dijit.Calendar");
    dojo.ready(function(){      
        // create the Calendar:
        var selectedDate = null;

        var calendar_body = new dojox.widget.Calendar({
                value: new Date(),

                onValueSelected: function(date){calendarDateClicked(date);
                }
            }, "calendar_body");



        //Set month in correct format
        function setMonth(month){
            switch(month)
            {
            case 1:
            month = "Jan";
            break;
            case 2:
            month = "Feb";
            break;
            }
            return month;
        }
        //create Click action
        function calendarDateClicked(date){
            var d = new Date(date);

            var month = (d.getMonth() + 1);
            month = setMonth(month);
            var day = '' + d.getDate() + ",";
            var year = d.getFullYear();
            //if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
            if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;


            var dateString = [month,day,year].join(" ");

            //var y = dojo.date.locale.format(d, {datePattern:"dd/MM/yyyy", selector: 'date'});


            dojo.byId('#{id:hiddenCalWidgetSelectedDate}').value = dateString
            //dojo.byId('#{id:hiddenCalWidgetSelectedDate}').value = y;

            //dojo.byId('#{id:calDate}').value = y;
            dojo.byId('#{id:calDate}').value = dateString;
            XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:mainPanel}",{});//Post Value to server
        }
    });
});
```